# WPF ComboBox Binding Errors

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I've searched for hours and could not find any existing solutions to the problem I'm having. So here it is please help if you can. When I bind the `ComboBox` `SelectedValuePath` I am seeing `BindingExpression path errors` in the output window:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'GeoUnitID' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.
>   This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data
>   yet. BindingExpression:Path=GeoUnitID; DataItem=null; target element
>   is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot
>   retrieve value due to missing information.
>   BindingExpression:Path=GeoUnitID; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot
>   retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is
>   detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value.
>   BindingExpression:Path=GeoUnitID; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the
>   binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead.
>   BindingExpression:Path=GeoUnitID; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

The binding does work correctly, and the correct values are displayed, but I suspect these errors are the reason for the poor performance I am seeing (scrolling/loading timing).  Here's the relevant xaml:

```
   <ListView x:Name="lvItems" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
       ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
       gisc:ListViewSort.IsSortable="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns> 
                <!-- selecteditembinding: source:Int32, dest:dest:Int16  -->
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="CountryOfIssue" Content="CountryOfIssue" />
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <ComboBox 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=Countries}" 
                                    SelectedValuePath="GeoUnitID"                                            
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CountryOfIssueID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="ShortName" 
                                    Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I've verified the `ItemsSource` collection does not have null items. I've also tried an entirely different structure (WPF `DataGrid` instead of the `ListView`/`GridView` structure shown above with similar results). The scrolling performance is terrible for a small number of rows (~400). I initially searched for ways to improve scrolling performance, but those solutions did little to help. There are TONS of these binding errors so I strongly suspect that is the root cause.

**EDIT** (added relevant types)

//Listview collection (dependency property defined in the UserControl):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Items",
    typeof(CorpActionAutoPostConfigs),
    typeof(CorpActionAutoPostConfigControl2)
);

public CorpActionAutoPostConfigs Items
{
    get { return (CorpActionAutoPostConfigs)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

//The type (observable collection) that the ListView is bound to

```
public class CorpActionAutoPostConfigs : ObservableCollection<CADB.CorpActionAutoPostConfig>, ICloneable
{
    //code omitted
}
```

//The collection item type (defined in an assembly so i don't have the source code).  But I wrote the relevant public property below.

```
CADB.CorpActionAutoPostConfig
{
    public int CountryOfIssueID {set; get;}
}
```

//ComboBox items collection (dependency property defined in UserControl)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CountriesProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
"Countries",
typeof(Countries),
typeof(CorpActionAutoPostConfigControl2)
);

public Countries Countries
{
    get { return (Countries)GetValue(CountriesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CountriesProperty, value); }
}
```

//The type (observable collection) that the ComboBox is bound to

```
public class Countries : ObservableCollection<RDS.Country>
{
    //code omitted
}
```

//The collection item type (defined in an assembly so i don't have the source code).  But I wrote the relevant public properties below.

```
RDS.Country
{
    public int GeoUnitID {get;}
    public string ShortName {get;}  
}
```

Comment: What's with all the binding to your Window as a data source (Binding ElementName=myWindow)?  I think that's going to kick off errors if the Window hasn't been rendered. Difficult to say without seeing a gigantic pile of your code, but the 'normal' way of doing this is to bind to a context, not a control.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  "myWindow" is just the name of the control the that contains the above xaml (so RelativeSource/Self would've worked).  Just in case window rendering was somehow affecting the binding, I separated out a ViewModel and set the DataContext appropriately and the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you post your window's code behind (with the `Items` and `Countries` properties), the class of your item (with the `CountryOfIssueID` property) and the class of your country (with the `GeoUnitID` and `ShortName` properties)? I did not manage to reproduce your errors, but replacing the `ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=Countries}"` by  `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Countries, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"` can be a lead.

Comment: Just to rule it out as a source of disruption, is there anything weird or wonderful in GridEditStyle?

Comment: I posted the relevant properties and types.  And nothing wonderful in GridEditStyle (simply sets some alignments).

Comment: I can't reproduce it using your code, even if I put some null items or values in my collections. Maybe you should create a separate simple project containing just your `Window`, your `ListView` and `ComboBox` and two `ObservableCollection`, without any styles. Maybe something else in your project produces those errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It actually led me the right direction.  I've been able to eliminate most of the binding errors.  I'll post what the issue was and my solution once I completely understand it.